# How to save mail and send it later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, mailer

I want to save the mail sent on certain days (eg.sunday) in database and then send them on next day.
I want to know if it is possible.

And how to save the mail object into database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to configure a cronjob which is executed every sunday, and which retrieves your mail-content and then sends it out...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) plugin which is easy to use, you can postpone the long-computing methods to do it later in the background (with optional exact timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

If you end up using cron take a look at the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. It makes it easy to manage cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

CollectiveIdea's [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) allows you to handle email sending easily. You can call the delay method on any object and it allows you to process anything in background. Checkout the **Queuing Jobs** section in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, delayed job is the best option. The easy tutorial on how to use it is [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job?view=asciicast).